# I need to replace the character \\ of a string and read with JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, json

When saving the JSON object in Mysql with JSON.stringify it puts the character "\" in the string. I am building a VIEW and I need to separate the data with json_extract, for that I used the MySql REPLACE command but the return is null.

**EDITED**

**JSON IN FIELD "DADOS" (LONGTEXT)**

```
{  
   "pessoal":"[{\"nome\":\"Marie Luiza Novaes\",\"nascimento\":\"1994-06-20\",\"civil\":\"Casado(a)\",\"sexo\":\"F\",\"rg\":\"469326293\",\"cpf\":\"06649073504\"}]",
   "contato":[],
   "interesse":[],
   "adicional":[],
   "profissional":[],
   "academico":[],
   "anotacoes":[],
   "extras":"[]"
}
```

*1 - GET NOME*

```
SELECT
  json_extract (REPLACE(dados,'\\"','"'), '$.pessoal[0].nome') dados
FROM
  cadastro
```

*2 - GET NOME*

```
SELECT
  json_extract (REPLACE(dados,'\\',''), '$.pessoal[0].nome') dados
FROM
  cadastro
```

**[TEST](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5f461f1e4bf8fb0892cd9be62dd2fb23)**

Comment: That backslash is just an artifact, indicating the the double quotes which are escaped as `\"` are just _literal_ double quotes.  _Dont'_ make an attempt to remove the backslash, because it isn't really there in the JSON.

Comment: I tried without REPLACE the result is still null

Answer (score 0):

I see multiple problems with your current approach.  First, the JSON literal text in your column appears to be somewhat malformed.  The JSON array does not take double quotes, because it is part of the JSON structure.  Second, the JSON path syntax you are using is also off.  The following exact setup is working for me:

```
WITH cadastro AS (
    SELECT '{"pessoal":[{"nome":"Marie Luiza Novaes","nascimento":"1994-06-20","civil":"Casado(a)","sexo":"F","rg":"469326293","cpf":"06649073504"}],
        "contato":[],
        "interesse":[],
        "adicional":[],
        "profissional":[],
        "academico":[],
        "anotacoes":[],
        "extras":[]}' AS dados
)

SELECT
    JSON_EXTRACT(dados, '$.pessoal[0].nome') dados
FROM cadastro;
```

### Demo

The output from this query is `"Marie Luiza Novaes"`.

Comment: I edited based on your example, now with the full data I have in the field and it still doesn't work

Comment: Why did you change the question after someone has already answered?

Comment: Sorry Tim, your example really worked, but I had forgotten the rest of the data, which led me to edit and I ask for your help again.

Comment: @alebarros I updated my answer.  This will be my last update here, so I hope it meets your expectations.